Spinning square of ASCII symbols issues
everyone!
I made a little program of a square spinning in terminal. It works actually, but not as I expected.
For some reason part of the characters is not printed after each rotation. Got no idea why.
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SIZE 100   // size of the field of characters
#define SQ_SIZE 10 // size of the square

char field[SIZE][SIZE] = {' '};
char fill_char = ' ';
char sq_char = '.';

typedef struct Coords {
  int x;
  int y;
} Coords;

// x and y coords of each point of the square
Coords coords_data[SQ_SIZE][SQ_SIZE];

// prints the field
// grid was used for debugging
void print_field(bool show_grid) {

  if (show_grid) {
    printf("\033[32;1m   ");
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
      printf("%3d", i);
    printf("\n\033[0m");
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    if (show_grid)
      printf("\033[32;1m%3d\033[0m", i);
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
      printf("%3c", field[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

// fills the entire field with fill_char
void fill_field(void) {
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
      field[i][j] = fill_char;
}

// creates the square and fill the coords_data with square's points' coords
void init_sqare(void) {
  int start_x = SIZE / 2 - SQ_SIZE / 2;
  int start_y = SIZE / 2 - SQ_SIZE / 2;

  for (int i = start_x; i < SQ_SIZE + start_x; i++)
    for (int j = start_y; j < SQ_SIZE + start_y; j++) {
      field[i][j] = sq_char;
      coords_data[i - start_x][j - start_y].x = i;
      coords_data[i - start_x][j - start_y].y = j;
    }
}

// for debugging
void show_coords(void) {
  for (int i = 0; i < SQ_SIZE; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SQ_SIZE; j++)
      printf("\t(%d, %d)", coords_data[i][j].x, coords_data[i][j].y);
    printf("\n");
  }
}

// changes the coords using the transition matrix
void change_coords(Coords *coords, double rad, int center_x, int center_y) {
  int x = coords->x - center_x;
  int y = coords->y - center_y;

  int new_x = round(x * cos(rad) - y * sin(rad)) + center_x;
  int new_y = round(x * sin(rad) + y * cos(rad)) + center_y;

  coords->x = new_x;
  coords->y = new_y;
}

// rotates the cube
void rotate(double rad) {
  int center_x = SIZE / 2;
  int center_y = SIZE / 2;

  fill_field();

  // clear old square and change coordinates
  for (int i = 0; i < SQ_SIZE; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SQ_SIZE; j++) {

      change_coords(&coords_data[i][j], rad, center_x,
                    center_y); // change coords

      // Ensure new coordinates are within bounds
      if (coords_data[i][j].x >= 0 && coords_data[i][j].x < SIZE &&
          coords_data[i][j].y >= 0 && coords_data[i][j].y < SIZE) {
        field[coords_data[i][j].x][coords_data[i][j].y] =
            sq_char; // fill new square
      }
    }
  }
}

int main(void) {
  fill_field();
  init_sqare();

  printf("\n\n");
  double angle_mult = M_PI / 12;
  double angle = 0;

  while (true) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
      rotate(angle);
      angle += i * angle_mult;
      printf("\033[s");
      printf("\033[1;32m");
      print_field(false);
      printf("\033[0m");
      printf("\033[u\033[2J");
      usleep(500000);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

What is more interesting, with each rotatation more and more characters disappear and only several structures like circles remain.
Help with solving this issue.

Note that char field[SIZE][SIZE] = {' '}; only initializes one element to a space,  the rest are null characters.

When you rotate, two dots can fall in the same integer coordinates due to rounding. Once this happens, you've lost the distinction between the two points for ever.

Yes. Your are rounding x and y coordinates. So sometimes 2 different points become the same points after rotation. For example, let A=(7,1) and B=(8,1); around center (0,0), a rotation with angle π/12 (the one of your code) of A, A'=(6.502661; 2.777659). And rotation of B is B'=(7.468588; 3.036478). Both are (7,3) once rounded.
And since once two points are identical, they never separate again, yes, after a while you have less and less apparent points (more and more points are confused into a single coordinates).
Rounding is a necessity for ascii art, I get that. But you should round only at the last moment, when drawing.
In other words, your .x and .y should be double, not int. Your change_coord should not round anything. Your coord_data should not be organized in a grid. No reason for that. They are just a bunch of points. At no point you take advantage of the fact that you can retrieve the coords of a points at a given place in the screen. You just for loop all possible grid cell any way. You could have just an array of N coords.
(Well, you could keep the array 2D if you wish, for example indexed by their initial coordinates. But no reason to keep moving those data. This is what I've chosen in following code, to minimize the number of change from your code).
And only your field variable should be a grid, that you fill from the points in coord_data, by rounding their value.
So, something like
typedef struct Coords {
    double x;
    double y;
} Coords;

void change_coords(Coords *coords, double rad, int center_x, int center_y) {
  double x = coords->x - center_x;
  double y = coords->y - center_y;

  double new_x = x * cos(rad) - y * sin(rad) + center_x;
  double new_y = x * sin(rad) + y * cos(rad) + center_y;

  coords->x = new_x;
  coords->y = new_y;
}

void rotate(double rad) {
   // ... unchanged code omitted ...
      // Ensure new coordinates are within bounds
      if (coords_data[i][j].x >= 0 && coords_data[i][j].x < SIZE &&
          coords_data[i][j].y >= 0 && coords_data[i][j].y < SIZE) {
        field[(int)round(coords_data[i][j].x)][(int)round(coords_data[i][j].y)] = sq_char; // fill new square
      }
    }
  }
}

Note that this is probably still not what you wanted. There are other problems. But the one you asked about is solved: point doesn't disappear progressively.
Yet, there are some holes sometimes. Due to the same rounding problem. But temporary. (again (7,1) and (8,1) are both send to (8,3) after 1 rotation. But since it is only where they are displayed in that frame that coincide, not their actual coordinates, they separate again later).
If you want to solve that you need some very different strategy. For example, explicitly draw rotated square, not from an array of points, but from its corners. Or even just center and angle (so write a function that decides explicitly whether point of coordinates (i,j) is inside square with center (x0,y0), length L and angle α).

Sorry for answering that late. Your advice of changing the approach helped a lot! I managed to make a program that can rotate a regular polygon with any number of angles. Thank you!
